# How to get last data in double data and delete the other with query

Tags: sql, postgresql, double, max

I have the data in table A with double or more. And i want get the last data input and delete the old data. How?

I try select with distinc and inner join, but when execute to delete the old and last data is include. so i have some issue.

Select * from A where po in (select max(po) from B)

The result is data invalid.

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please. A few rows of data would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

First i make new table result from `distinc` table A.

`create table c AS

select distinct po, plan_ref from A group by po, plan_ref`

```
After that, copy the table A. Let say it begin table B.

delete all the data in table A.

`INSERT INTO A (id, po
, plan_ref
, cust_order
, cust_code
, cust_name
, destination
, art_no
, art_name
, cust_reqdate
, posdd
, podd
, ship_date
, container
, ship
, plant_cell
, cbm
, remark
, upload_by
, upload_date)
select MAX(a.id), MAX (a.po)
, MAX(a.plan_ref)
, MAX(a.cust_order)
, MAX(a.cust_code)
, MAX(a.cust_name)
, MAX(a.destination)
, MAX(a.art_no)
, MAX(a.art_name)
, MAX(a.cust_reqdate)
, MAX(a.posdd)
, MAX(a.podd)
, MAX(a.ship_date)
, MAX(a.container)
, MAX(a.ship)
, MAX(a.plant_cell)
, MAX(a.cbm)
, MAX(a.remark)
, MAX(a.upload_by)
, MAX(a.upload_date) from C b
inner join B a on a.plan_ref = b.plan_ref
AND a.po = b.po GROUP BY a.po`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all but the maximum `po` (as suggested by your code), then you can do:

```
delete from a
    where po < (select max(a2.po) from a a2);
```

More commonly, you would want to keep the maximum `po` based on some other column.  For that, use a correlated subquery:

```
delete from a
    where po < (select max(a2.po) from a a2 where a2.? = a.?);  -- ? is for the grouping column
```

Comment: it will delete the all data where po is double, i want keep the last and delete old po.
But i will try first.
Thanks.